# the xpath is not valid because either the xpath syntax is incorrect or not supported by excel - mapping schemas programatically

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xpath, xsd

I've been following this tutorial of converting XML data into a schema by reading the XML data into a string:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469857(v=office.14).aspx

And then using this tutorial to import XML Data and the XML Schema to Create the Mapped List:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469859(v=office.14).aspx

I have trialled the code using the XML data they provide and it works. 
Their XML Data:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<BookInfo>
   <Book>
      <ISBN>989-0-487-04641-2</ISBN>
      <Title>My World</Title>
      <Author>Nancy Davolio</Author>
      <Quantity>121</Quantity>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <ISBN>981-0-776-05541-0</ISBN>
      <Title>Get Connected</Title>
      <Author>Janet Leverling</Author>
      <Quantity>435</Quantity>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <ISBN>999-1-543-02345-2</ISBN>
      <Title>Honesty</Title>
      <Author>Robert Fuller</Author>
      <Quantity>315</Quantity>
   </Book>
</BookInfo>
```

My XML Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<DEFTABLE>

  <TABLE DATACENTER="XXXX" LAST_UPLOAD="XXXX" TABLE_NAME="XXXX" USED_BY_CODE="XXXX">
</TABLE>

</DEFTABLE>
```

My code is:

```
Sub CreateXMLList()
   Dim oMyMap As XmlMap
   Dim strXPath As String
   Dim oMyList As ListObject
   Dim oMyNewColumn As ListColumn

   ' Add a schema map.
   ' ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Myschema.xsd")
   ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add ("G:\Sharepoint\EMSCHEDULES\ALL_PROD_EM_SCHEDULES_140331.xsd")

   ' Identify the target schema map.
   Set oMyMap = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps("DEFTABLE_Map1")

   ' Create a new list in A1.
   Range("A1").Select
   Set oMyList = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add

   ' Find the first element to map.
   strXPath = "/DEFTABLE/TABLE/TABLE_NAME"
   ' Map the element.
   oMyList.ListColumns(1).XPath.SetValue oMyMap, strXPath


   ' Give the columns logical names
   oMyList.ListColumns(1).Name = "Table Name"
```

I get the following error: 
the xpath is not valid because either the xpath syntax is incorrect or not supported by excel 
On line:

```
oMyNewColumn.XPath.SetValue oMyMap, strXPath
```

Can anyone explain why it is not working?

Comment: The error line you're referring to doesn't appear to be in the code you provided. And the following is probably unrelated to that error, but I believe the correct XPath in this case should be `/DEFTABLE/TABLE/@TABLE_NAME`. Can you provide us with the contents of your XSD file?

Comment: Hi JLRishe - thank you for replying - and you were correct I needed to put the @ symbol in front for it to work!! Cheers!!  And the error code was from: 
oMyList.ListColumns(1).XPath.SetValue oMyMap, strXPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as discussed in the comments)

It appears that the XPath was being rejected because it was incorrect for the data you were trying to query and presumably didn't match the XSD you were providing. The correct XPath in this case would be:

```
/DEFTABLE/TABLE/@TABLE_NAME
```